# sendmail.php woes.

Tags: php, html, email

I have 2 pieces of code and I cannot get my mail to send from an email form. I think I am missing my sendmail.php file. can anyone help me in writing this or using a script to be able to use it? The code that I have is.

```
  var name = jQuery("input#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
  jQuery("span#name_error").show();
  jQuery("input#name").focus();
  return false;
}
  var email = jQuery("input#email").val();
  if (email == "") {
  jQuery("span#email_error").show();
  jQuery("input#email").focus();
  return false;
}

var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(!emailReg.test(email)) {
jQuery("span#email_error2").show();
jQuery("input#email").focus();
  return false;
}

var subject = jQuery("input#subject").val();

  var msg = jQuery("textarea#msg").val();
  if (msg == "") {
  jQuery("span#msg_error").show();
  jQuery("textarea#msg").focus();
  return false;
}

    var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&msg=' + msg;
    //alert (dataString);return false;

  jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "sendemail.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    jQuery('#contactform').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    jQuery('#message').html("<strong>Contact Form Submitted!</strong>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      jQuery('#message');
    });
  }
 });
return false;
});
```

});'

and

```
<div id="contactform">
                              <form id="contact" action="#">
                                  <fieldset>
                                      <span class="error" id="name_error">Please enter name !</span>
                                      <span class="error" id="email_error">Please enter email address !</span>
                                      <span class="error" id="email_error2">Please enter valid email address !</span>
                                      <span class="error" id="msg_error">Please enter message !</span>
                                      <label for="name" id="name_label">Your Name (required)</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50" value="" class="text-input" />
                                      <label for="email" id="email_label">Your Email (required)</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="50" value="" class="text-input" />
                                      <label for="subject" id="subject_label">Subject</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" size="50"  value="" class="text-input" />
                                      <label for="msg" id="msg_label">Your Message (required)</label>
                                      <textarea rows="8" name="msg" id="msg" class="text-input"></textarea>
                                      <br />
                                      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send"/>
                                  </fieldset>
                              </form>
                        </div><!-- end contactform -->
```

Please help.

Comment: You don't have any PHP code at all??

Comment: No. I did not have the sendmail.php. I was curious if I could use a template of some code. Ive tried 3 but non had worked. I was wondering which one might for this and if not can one be modified to fit this code and if someone could help. Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you don't have experience coding in PHP. If that is the case, I suggest you learn that first before you attempt these types of projects.

Comment: Just change your jquery post query like as follows "jQuery.post("sendemail.php", { name: name,email: email,subject: subject,msg: msg, },
  function(data) {
    jQuery('#contact').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    
 jQuery('#message').html(data)
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      jQuery('#message');
    });
 });"

Comment: Hi John, Thanks again. However with just the original contact.js and your sendemail.php code it works, however it will not display any information in the email message of the information inputed. With your jquery post edit for contact.js I get a whole lot of sql errors and am correctly inputting the information in. What could be causing this and what would I need to do to get the info to display correctly in the email?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to send e-mail from your from

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $to = "someone@example.com"; // Replace This Id With Another ( Where U Need to Send )
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // Enter A Subject..
    $message = 'Name : '.$_POST['name'].'<br/> Email : '.$_POST['email'].'<br/> Subject : '.$_POST['subject'].'<br/> Message : '.$_POST['msg'].' ';
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
}
?>
```

*** You Need To Replace `$to` value with your value for ***
For eg if you need to send the mail to `abc@va.com` use this `$to = "abc@va.com";`

Answer (score 0):

**Just try with the following example :**

***sendmail.php***

```
<?php
$uname     =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$uemail    =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$usubject  =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
$umsg      =   mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);
$to = 'john@gmail.com'; //Here add your to email where you have to sent after submitting the form
$subject = 'Test Mail';
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($uemail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($uemail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>User Name :</strong> </td><td>".$uname."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email :</strong> </td><td>".$uemail."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Subject :</strong> </td><td>".$usubject."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td><strong>Message :</strong> </td><td>".$umsg."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "<strong>Contact Form Submitted!</strong>";
?>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi, John Peter. Thanks for your response. I tried this and with the code I have listed one is set as contact.html in the root dir, and the second was in the js dir. I have saved your code as sendmail.php and put it in both these dir and mail is still not being send. Is there something that I am missing here? Thank you (also I did change the email from your code)

Comment: Hi John, Thanks again. However with just the original contact.js and your sendemail.php code it works, however it will not display any information in the email message of the information inputed. With your jquery post edit for contact.js I get a whole lot of sql errors and am correctly inputting the information in. What could be causing this and what would I need to do to get the info to display correctly in the email?